# What to do on east coast of Sri Lanka in May

Tags: southeast-asia, sri-lanka

I'm going to Sri Lanka with my wife for 1 week early May. I think we will stay Trincomalee/Nilaveli as we enjoy beaches and snorkeling, but are there any day trips that we can do from there. I was thinking about Anuradhapura, anything else that can be visited as a day trip?

Answer (score 3):

Anuradhapura is interesting if it's on your way (and it probably is).  But do note that transportation in Sri Lanka takes a very long time per distance travelled.  Whereas at home you might compute your average travel speed as 80 km/h, in Sri Lanka 20 km/h would be more realistic.

If you like trains, you should consider taking one from Colombo to Kandy (a famous route), and perhaps stop in Dambulla or Polonnaruwa.  I would recommend spending a night wherever you decide to go, because it takes quite a bit of time to travel from Trincomalee to most other places.

Comment: I'm from Sri Lanka, but I disagree with the 20km/h. It's too slow even for our standards :) there is an A grade road from Anuradhapura to Trinco. You can even go far East beaches from Trinco and come back the same day. This however assumes that you have your own vehicle and you are OK to drive in left lane.